# java iterate over map< string, list< string> , getordefault method

Tags: java, list, generics, java-8

I have a map of < string, List< String type>>, 
What I am trying to do is add a string to map value if list is present, else create a list and add it to the list and insert in `map`. 
`s1`, `s2` are strings.

Code:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

map.put(s1,(map.getOrDefault(s1, new LinkedList<String>())).add(s2));
```

Error:

```
error: incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to List<String>
```

What's wrong with this !!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

add method of list 'map.getOrDefault(s1, new LinkedList())).add(s2)' is return boolean so you have to do it in separate line

so try like this

```
    Map< String, List< String>> map = new HashMap<>();

    List<String> list = map.get(s1);
    if(list == null){
      list = new LinkedList<>();
      map.put(s1,list);
    }
    list.add(s2);
```

If use java 8 and need to do in single line do like this

```
    map.computeIfAbsent(s1, k -> new LinkedList<>()).add(s2);
```

Comment: Since [`getOrDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-) was added in Java 8, it's a fair assumption that OP has Java 8.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for your input I didn't use 'getOrDefault' method before. thanks again for your valuable input.

Comment: @Holger yep true I use LinkedList because question asked for LinkedList otherwise ArrayList is better. Thanks for your input

Comment: Had an error in my previous comment. The Op’s original approach would work with `List<String> list = map.getOrDefault(s1, new LinkedList<>()); list.add(s2); map.putIfAbsent(s1, list);`, but, of course, `map.computeIfAbsent(s1, k -> new LinkedList<>()).add(s2);` still is straight forward and more efficient. And as said, [even better would be `map.computeIfAbsent(s1, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(s2);`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/322715/2711488)…

Comment: this really helps, thanks @janith1024 and I see I missed on usage of lambda or anonymous functions in Java 8. I was able to do it in other ways, but yes this computeIfAbsent is really a one line saviour

Answer (score 1):

This call,

```
(map.getOrDefault(s1, new LinkedList())).add(s2)
```

Returns a `boolean` primitive, which can not be casted to a `List`. That why you are getting this error.

You can solve it like so,

```
map.compute(s1, (k, v) -> v == null ? new LinkedList<>() : v).add(s2);
```

The trick here is, `map.compute()` returns the new value associated with the specified key, and then you can add the s2 String literal into that afterward.

Comment: [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) would be better than `compute` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

// gets the value if it is present in the map else initialze the list
List<String> li = map.getOrDefault(s1,new LinkedList<>());

li.add(s2);

map.put(s1,li);
```